# How to write a FirstOrException() extension method compatible with LINQ to SQL (and high performing)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-sql, extension-methods, linq-to-objects

Quite often I find myself writing code like this:

```
Dim oRenewalOrder = (From c in dc.Orders _
                     Where c.CustomerID = iCustomerID _
                     And c.Type = "RENEWAL").FirstOrDefault()

If oRenewalOrder Is Nothing Then
   Throw New Exception("Can't find renewal order for customer " & iCustomerID) ' or assert, if you prefer
End If

' Continue processing...
```

I would prefer to use the First() method instead, since it already throws an exception when there is no element. But that  exception tells you nothing about what caused it, making it harder to debug. So I want to write a FirstOrException() extension method that I can use like this:

```
Dim oRenewalOrder = (From c in dc.Orders _
                     Where c.CustomerID = iCustomerID _
                     And c.Type = "RENEWAL").FirstOrException("Can't find renewal order for customer " & iCustomerID)

' Continue processing...
```

The problem is that it's hard to write such a method in a generic way, to work with both LINQ to Objects *and* take advantage of the query optimizations present LINQ to SQL. The best I can come up with is this:

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns the first element of a sequence.
    ''' If the sequence is empty, an InvalidOperationException is thrown with the specified message.
    <Extension()> _
    Function FirstOrException(Of T)(ieThis As IEnumerable(Of T), sMessage As String) As T
        Try
            Return ieThis.First()
        Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
            Throw New InvalidOperationException(sMessage, ex)
        End Try
    End Function
```

I also wrote another equivalent extension method for IEnumerable(Of T), to cover the LINQ to Objects case. These work well, but it seems bad to have to catch an exception and rethrow it. I tried a different approach, using Take(1) and AsEnumerable(), but when I profiled it, it was running two separate SELECT TOP 1 statements:

```
    <Extension()> _
    Function FirstOrException(Of T)(iqThis As IQueryable(Of T), sMessage As String) As T
        Dim aFirst = iqThis.Take(1).AsEnumerable()
        If aFirst.Count() <= 0 Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException(sMessage)
        Else
            Return aFirst(0)
        End If
    End Function
```

So I'm back to the exception handling method. I don't like it because there is a possibility that whatever LINQ provider is underlying the collection will throw an InvalidOperationException when there is a different problem -- not a lack of results, but something else. This would cause my code to mistakenly think there were no results, when in fact it was a different problem entirely.

...

Well, as so often happens when you type up a detailed question, I think I found a better solution, and I will post it in the answers below. But I'll leave the question open in case anyone finds something better :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `Take(1).ToArray()` is the cleanest solution. It causes only a single query to be sent to the database. Note that in the code below I am doing separate extension methods for IEnumerable and IQueryable to support both LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Objects.

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns the first element of a sequence.
    ''' If the sequence is empty, an InvalidOperationException is thrown with the specified message.
    <Extension()> _
    Function FirstOrException(Of T)(ieThis As IEnumerable(Of T), sMessage As String) As T
        Dim aFirst = ieThis.Take(1).ToArray()
        If aFirst.Length <= 0 Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException(sMessage)
        Else
            Return aFirst(0)
        End If
    End Function

     ''' <summary>
     ''' Returns the first element of a queryable (e.g. LINQ to SQL) sequence.
     ''' If the sequence is empty, an InvalidOperationException is thrown with the specified message.
    <Extension()> _
    Function FirstOrException(Of T)(iqThis As IQueryable(Of T), sMessage As String) As T
        Dim aFirst = iqThis.Take(1).AsEnumerable()
        If aFirst.Length <= 0 Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException(sMessage)
        Else
            Return aFirst(0)
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: I'll accept my own answer as I haven't received any suggestions other than devundef's, which, while fast and simple for collections of reference types, won't work for collections of value types.

Answer (score 0):

You already did the extension without change the optimizations for Linq-to-sql. You'll need to hit the database at least once to check if is something there. You don't need to use `Take(1)`, just call `FirstOrDefault()` and check if it returns `Nothing`.

```
Function GetFirstOrException(Of T)(sMessage As String, sFirst as T) as T
   if (T is Nothing) 
      Throw New InvalidOperationException(sMessage)
   Return T
End Function

 <Extension()> _
Function FirstOrException(Of T)(iqThis As IQueryable(Of T), sMessage As String) As T
    Return GetFirstOrException(sMessage, idThis.FirstOrDefault())
End Function

 <Extension()> _
Function FirstOrException(Of T)(iqThis As IEnumerable(Of T), sMessage As String) As T
    Return GetFirstOrException(sMessage, idThis.FirstOrDefault())
End Function
```

Comment: I didn't think of calling a helper method from my extension methods. This is even better. Thanks.

Comment: Actually we don't even need to use a helper method, do we? We can test for nothing right inside the extension methods... And now I remember why I didn't do it this way: I want the methods to work for value types as well as reference types. Value types cannot be null/Nothing. For example, in a List of Int32's, it is impossible to tell via FirstOrDefault() if there was no item in the list, or if the first item was equal to zero (the default value of Int32). That's why I needed the Take().